Struggling to prove that the Hessian is PSD for simple linear regression least squares method
I am looking at the simplest case of minimizing the following over $b_0$ and $b_1$:
$$(y_1 - [b_0 + b_1 x_1])^2 + \ldots + (y_n - [b_0 + b_1 x_n])^2$$
To establish that this function is convex in $b_0$ and $b_1$, I have obtained the Hessian like so:
$$\Big(\begin{matrix}
2n & 2(x_1 + \ldots + x_n)\\
2(x_1 + \ldots + x_n) & 2(x_1^2 + \ldots + x_n^2)
\end{matrix}\Big)$$
I would be done if I show that the determinant of this $2\times 2$ matrix is nonnegative. But here, I am stuck with having to prove the following inequality:
$$n(x_1^2 + \ldots + x_n^2) \geq (x_1 + \ldots + x_n)^2$$
Is there a simple way to prove this inequality?
I have looked at a few books on regression on this, including Wackerley, Mendenhall and Scheaffer. While they derive the first order conditions, the second order necessary conditions for a global minima are not considered/provided. Any help is appreciated.

Edited to add. Ah, found a reasonably elegant way on probing this further.
At some point in trying to prove this by induction, I have the following inequality to prove:
$$x_1^2 + \ldots + x_n^2 + nx_{n+1}^2 \geq 2(x_1 + \ldots + x_n)x_{n+1}$$
But this is easily proven by re-writing the LHS as:
$$(x_1^2 + x_{n+1}^2)+\ldots + (x_n^2 + x_{n+1}^2) \geq 2(x_1 + \ldots + x_n)x_{n+1}$$
Then, by bringing over the RHS to the LHS, we have:
$$(x_1^2 + x_{n+1}^2 - 2x_1 x_{n+1})+\ldots + (x_n^2 + x_{n+1}^2 - 2x_n x_{n+1}) \geq 0$$
which is obviously true.

have a look at Gram Matrices positive definiteness

Sums of squares always have positive semidefinite Hessians: in that degree of abstraction, the result is trivial to show using basic properties of arithmetic.  Apply that.

Concerning the inequality: consider the uniform distribution on the numbers $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n).$ Compute its variance and compare that to zero: done.

This is an instance of the power mean inequality.  A proof appears here on CV at Prove that $E(X^n)^{1/n}$ is non-decreasing for non-negative random variables, but since it is stated in terms of expectations, let me translate that into the present notation.
For finite vectors $\mathbf x = (x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$ of non-negative real numbers and a real number $p \ne 0,$ the $p^\text{th}$ power mean is the back-transformed average of the transformed components,
$$M_p(\mathbf x) = \left(\frac{x_1^p + x_2^p + \cdots + x_n^p}{n}\right)^{1/p}.$$
(For $p=0$ this extends naturally to the geometric mean, where the transformation is the logarithm, and for $p=\infty$ it extends to the supremum norm equal to the largest of the $x_i.$)
The power mean inequality states this function increases with $p.$  That is, for any $p, q\in \mathbb R \cup\{\infty\}$ with $p\le q$ and for all non-negative vectors $\mathbb x,$
$$M_p(\mathbb x) \le M_q(\mathbb x).$$
The case $p=1, q = 2$ is
$$\frac{x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n}{n} = M_1(\mathbb x)\ \le\ M_2(\mathbb x) = \left(\frac{x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots+x_n^2}{n}\right)^{1/2}.$$
Because both means are non-negative, the inequality is preserved when both sides are squared.  Do so; and then clear the denominators by multiplying both sides by $n^2.$  The result is
$$n(x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n)^2 \le x_1^2 + x_2^2 + \cdots + x_n^2,$$
QED.

Returning to the motivating question, the convexity of the original function is more easily demonstrated directly.  Writing $\beta = (b_0, b_1),$ that function is of the form
$$f(\beta) = ||\mathbf y - \mathbb X\beta||^2 = (\mathbf y - \mathbb X\beta)^\prime(\mathbf y - \mathbb X\beta)$$
for a vector $\mathbb y$ and matrix $\mathbb X$ that you can read directly from the equation.  Fixing any vectors $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and differentiating the function of a real value $t$ given by $f(\alpha + t\beta)$ twice with respect to $t$ gives
$$\frac{\mathrm d^2}{\mathrm d t^2}f(\alpha + t\beta) = \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d t}(-2)(\mathbf y - \mathbb X(\alpha + t\beta))^\prime (\mathbb X\beta) = 2\left(\beta^\prime\mathbb X^\prime\right) \left(\mathbb X \beta\right) = 2||\mathbb X \beta||^2.$$
Squares are, by definition, non-negative, whence the Hessian of $f$ is everywhere non-negative.  That is one characterization of a convex function, QED.
